# Where to stop timer when user stop the app while timer is running

Tags: swift3

newBie in swift.

If user stop the app or swipe to stop the app WHILE the timer is running. Do I need to garbage collect the timer or where to stop the timer. If this is not handle, will it cause any problem?

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.setUpTimerCountDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timer: Timer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.updateValue), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if self.timer != nil{

            self.timer.invaidate()

            self.timer = nil
        }
    }

    func updateValue(){

        print("Timer is call")
    }
}
```